# Wondering what does "my treat" mean here

Tags: word-meaning

I just herad it in a TV series from satelite

1. My treat.
2. My treat.
3. No my treat
4. Ok your treat.

Comment: definition: [treat](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/treat) - noun 1. or 2. depending on the context.

Answer (score 5):

It means "I will pay for this", as in "I will treat you to this". Usually said in the context of a restaurant meal, or possibly an activity such as going to a movie or concert.

Comment: Yes; in the context of the television script, it's a short dispute about who will pay, with both parties initially offering to pay. In a comedy, a man and a woman might have this conversation when they are trying to decide if they are "on a date," or merely dining out together.